# Compare an input array with string

Tags: c++, dev-c++

How can use the proper code to compare an input array with string?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char user[30] ;
  string nama[5]="ali33,abu123,ahmad456,kasim123,rahmat123";
  int w,i ;

  cout<<"username : ";
  cin>>user[30];

  for(i=0;i>=0;++i)
  {
    w=strcmp(nama[i],user);
  }
```

I'm using Dev-C++, and the error is on this line:

```
w=strcmp(nama[i],user)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to create five strings? And what do you think `cin>>user[30];` does? And your `for` loop makes no sense. Basically, most of your code makes no sense, and without comments, we have no way to know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Is this a real code and a real location of error? And what is an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`strcmp()`**is used when comparing c-string data types. Convert your char data type to string and use compare function as illustrated below**`

int main()
{
    char user[30];
    string nama[5] = { "ali33","abu123","ahmad456","kasim123","rahmat123" };
    int w = -99;
    int i;

    cout << "username : ";
    cin >> user[30];

    string temp(user);

    for (i = 0; i < 5;  i++)
    {
        w = nama[i].compare(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you study this:

```
std::vector<string> nama = { "ali33", "abu123", "ahmad456",
                             "kasim123", "rahmat123" };
string user;
cout << "username : ";
int w = -1;
if (cin >> user)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nama.size(); ++i)
        if (nama[i] == user)
             w = i;
    if (w != -1)
        std::cout << user << " found at [" << w << "]\n";
    else
        std::cout << user " not found\n";
}
```

Notes: use `std::vector` not arrays until you understand the differences, and `std::string` for any text.  You could use the C++ Standard Library function `std::find()` to see if the `user` value appears in `nama`, but it's good to learn how to write a loop and do things yourself too.